# Is it possible to pull or pull out a machine gun if it's already in your hand?

Tags: word-usage, phrase-usage

Is it possible to pull or pull out a machine gun if it's already in your hand?

> He pulled (out) his machine gun and fired at the police.

Comment: Where do you think he might pull it from?

Comment: Well, just because it's *already* in your hand, doesn't mean you can't pull it from your waistband or whatever. The gun's being in your hand doesn't prevent it from remaining un-drawn.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Yeah, he pulls TRIGGER!

Comment: @userr2684291 The OP says, "He pulled (out) his machine gun and **fired at the police.**" What the gunner can do to fire the police by pulling is only the machine guns' trigger. Not that "pull".

Comment: @Kentaro The shooter could've been holding the gun the entire time in their hand, and then at some point actually pulled it out and started shooting.

Comment: This question doesn't make sense at all. The OP asks "Is it possible to pull or pull out a machine gun if it's already in your hand?" Does the OP intend to ask the "to abandon" his weapon voluntarily? Then he "drops(ed" his gun.

Comment: @userr2684291 Here "pull" has many meanings. The OP says "He pulled(out)...", well yeah, pull out does make sense but to pull doesn't make sense.

Comment: The answer is no: if the gun is already in your hand, you can't "pull it out". It's already **out**.

Comment: Joke from my youth - a truck driver pulled out to avoid a child... and fell out of bed.

Comment: What is the context of this question? Why would you say the gun is already in this person's hand?

Comment: Apart from language considerations, actual machine guns are pretty big to be pulled out of nowhere.

Comment: In some contexts a small automatic weapon might be called a "machine gun," but now I'm imagining someone trying to steal a full-sized machine gun, dragging it along the ground with one hand (so "pulling" the machine gun) while using a pistol in the other hand in an attempt to fight off the police. This is why context matters. (And yes, the thief could continue to pull the machine gun even though he already had it in is hand.)

Comment: I'm trying to imagine this with a Vickers K. Maybe a Bren or a Lewis gun. or a Sten.

Answer (score 5):

If the subject "pulls out" a gun, he is removing it from a holster, it at least from some concealed place. If he had the gun in his hand and they were both concealed in his coat, you could say

> He pulled out his gun and fired.

If the gun is already out, he can't pull it out again, but you could say something like

> He **raised** the gun and fired.

Or

> He **aimed** the gun and fired.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

[Pull out a gun](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/pull+a+gun)

**Pull (out) a gun (on someone)**

**to bring out a gun or knife suddenly so that it is ready for use against someone**.

> The police shot the thief when he **pulled out** a gun.

When you pull out a weapon you usually have it concealed at your waist or under your belt. You can't pull something out of your hand **unless you're a magician, then you can pull anything out from anywhere**.

Comment: So, the answer to the question is no. :)